# how to represent what functional dependencies are?

Tags: relational-theory

I'm trying to understand how to represent what **functional dependencies** are:

> A<sub>1</sub>, A<sub>2</sub>,..., A<sub>n</sub> → B
>
> If two tuples of R have the same attributes for A<sub>1</sub>, A<sub>2</sub>,..., A<sub>n</sub> then they have the same value for the attributes of B.

I am not able to represent it abstractly speaking... Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is such a brilliant example, but assume a relation like:

```
CREATE TABLE OWNERSHIP
( item_id
, ssn
, firstname
,    unique(item_id, ssn) );
```

Assume the f.d.:

```
ssn -> firstname
```

For the tuples:

```
(1, 'X', 'a name')  
(2, 'X', 'a name')
```

We can see that X in both cases has the name 'a name'.

Another way of thinking about it is: Assume two tuples of R have the same value of A but different values for B. Then by definition B can't be functionally dependent of A.